# How to pass props to class that extends Component<Props>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, react-props

I have a class I want to pass props to:

```js
type TestProps = {
    location: any
    setMill: (value: any) => void
}

class TestClass extends Component<TestProps> {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ userRoleRating: 5 });
    }

    render() {
        return <></>
    }
}

export default withRouter(TestClass as any)
```

And I have a functional component where I am calling the class component:

```js
type LayoutProps = {
  children?: React.ReactElement
  setMill: (value: any) => void
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = (props: LayoutProps) => {
  return <>
    <TestClass />
    <Container className="root-wrapper">{props.children}</Container>
    <Footer />
  </>
}

export default Layout
```

I was trying to pass props like this:

```js
type LayoutProps = {
  children?: React.ReactElement
  setMill: (value: any) => void
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = (props: LayoutProps) => {
  return <>
    <TestClass setMill={props.setMill}/>
    <Container className="root-wrapper">{props.children}</Container>
    <Footer />
  </>
}

export default Layout
```

But I get an error:

```
 Type '{ setMill: (value: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
(IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, 
StaticContext, unknown>, never> | (Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, 
StaticContext, unknown>, never> & { ...; }), any, any>> & 
Readonly<...>)'.

  Property 'setMill' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 
(IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, 
StaticContext, unknown>, never> | (Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, 
StaticContext, unknown>, never> & { ...; }), any, any>> & 
Readonly<...>)'.ts(2322)
```

I think the cause may be in the way I export my class component (using `withRouter`). What is the proper way to pass props to it?

Comment: When you say you "can't access the setMill prop", do you mean you're unfamiliar how to access props in class components (`this.props.setMill`), or do you mean that the value is `undefined`, or do you mean typescript is giving an error?

Comment: @NicholasTower, I mean I can't access the `setMill` prop not from inside the class component, but from the functional component. I get an error when trying to pass the prop. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I pass the props of `Layout` to my TestClass in curly braces:

```js
type LayoutProps = {
  children?: React.ReactElement
  setMill: (value: any) => void
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = (props: LayoutProps) => {
  return <>
    <TestClass {...props}/>
    <Container className="root-wrapper">{props.children}</Container>
    <Footer />
  </>
}

export default Layout
```

And it works just as intended. Please, correct me if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: {...props} is spreading the properties of props, should be similar to setMill=props.setMill but I'm not an expert of object oriented programming, not sure why you even need a class there. Depending on your IDE you should be able to hover on setMill and see what type is expected, same for props.setMill and see the difference.
Since you asked for somethings you might do wrong, I just commented to say that you use a lot of 'any' in your types which is kinda going against the idea of typescript itself. Learning how to type correctly will help you a lot in the future. setMill: (value: number)

Comment: Also small tip, you can do :
const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({setMill, children}) => ...
to directly access these variables in you functional component, saves you a lot of time when you use them more than once

Comment: @Tsuina, thank you for you comment, I'll take that under advisement and will try to change my code